# Can international students study via distance without applying for a visa?

Tags: united-states, international-students, distance-learning, visa

If an international student wants to study in a US degree program (AA, BA, MA, PhD, etc.), but entirely on-line while living in their home country, and without ever entering the US, can they skip all of the visa-related paperwork?

Answer (score 4):

Distance learning students who will not enter the United States are not required to get a U.S. visa. In fact, by federal law, online-only students are [not eligible](http://www.uc.edu/international/services/future/accepted.html) for a student visa.